# Why is my sudo generated file owned by root?

Tags: linux, unix, sudo

When I run '# sudo touch newfile' my expectation was that the file would be owned by me, not by root, as my understanding of sudo is that it is giving me, the user, root priviledges but does not actually switch the user.

Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of what sudo is about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `sudo`, you run a program as the superuser (root), so files that are created are created as the superuser.

Comment: "sudo, sudoedit — execute a command as another user"

Answer (score 6):

What mipadi said, which you can demonstrate by comparing the output of these two 'whoami' ("who am I?") commands:

> $ sudo whoami
>    $ whoami

Answer (score 4):

`sudo` (name comes from su "do" or super user "do") allows you to run command as root. It does not give your user different privileges. Therefore, when you run `#sudo touch newfile`
it is user root that executed command `touch newfile`and that is why newfile is owned by user root.

More information at [Sudo page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can think of the 'su' in sudo as "switch user". If you don't say which user to run as, it will default to `root`, the superuser, also associated with su.

`sudo -u yourself touch newfile` if you want the file to be owned by `yourself`.

Your assumption that `sudo` doesn't change the userid is correct in the perspective of the rest of your session. Think of it as `su` + `touch newfile` + `exit`. So, in your shell you "remain" yourself, but `sudo` executes your command in a new process with another effective userid.

Comment: The 'su' in 'sudo' means "Super User" (sudo = Super User Do), not "set userid". The command 'su' means 'Switch User'.